# Unexpected identifier In Typescript HTMLFormElement

Tags: javascript, typescript, forms, dom

```js
let forms = document.querySelector('.new-item-form') as HTMLFormElement ;


const typess = document.querySelector('#type') as HTMLSelectElement;
const tofrom = document.querySelector('#tofrom') as HTMLInputElement;
const details = document.querySelector('#details') as HTMLInputElement;
const amount = document.querySelector('#amount') as HTMLInputElement;

forms.addEventListener('submit' , (e:Event)=>{
   e.preventDefault()

   console.log(
    typess.value,
    tofrom.value,
    details.value,
    amount.valueAsNumber,

    )
})
```

i am trying to get value from my dom but it shows an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I don't know what is the reason of those error

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run _TypeScript_ as _JavaScript_. In TS it works fine, in JS it throws this error.

Comment: How can i solve this error any way ??

Comment: Does your file have the proper `.ts` extension instead of `.js`?

Comment: yes its .ts  see here is the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/132lp4v

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: i am new in typescript . just double click in index.html file then its open on the browser

Comment: You can't use TypeScript standalone. You have to transpile/compile it with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [TSC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use TypeScript as it is in browser. You have to transpile it with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or compile it with [TSC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript). Also you can use [ts-loader](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) if you are using Webpack.
As the definition of TypeScript says:

> TypeScript compiles to readable, standards-based JavaScript.
>
> Source: [TypeScript npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript)

If you are new to TypeScript you should check [their documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/) first.

Comment: Thanks i solve this problem useing parcel